# Freehand Editing 3 polygons not showing up

Tags: polygon, editing, archaeology

I'm using the Freehand Editing 3 plugin for QGIS 3.22.9 and I cannot get the polygons to show up. Currently I am digitizing archaeological drawings and I just don't want to draw every feature by clicking with the pen on the tablet.

So far what I have done is download the plugin, restart the program, remove and reinstall the plugin. I always check that the editing option is turned on and that the plugin is selected. I can see that the polygons are created because they show up in the feature table, but, despite turning labels on, the polygons never show up, even when changing the picture to hot pink. The only thing I can't do is change what I assume must be the width of the line, which is hard locked to 0,001 in the small text box next to the freehand editing plugin.

Has anyone else had this problem before? I am  losing my mind and most of the help I can find is for stuff I have  already done, i.e. checking that I am able to edit the layer.

Solved: The layer had been set in the wrong UTM Zone when created so the layers were being made, just outside of the area.

Answer (score 1):

[Since QGIS 3.20](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-streaming-digitizing-mode), you don't need a plugin. When digitizing, simply click `R` or the `Stream Digitizing` icon in the Digitizing Toolbar. [QGIS documentation says](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#geometry-editing-techniques):

> Stream Digitizing: draws lines in freehand mode, i.e. nodes are added
> following cursor movement in the map canvas and a Streaming Tolerance

[image]